# API Response to MVC Action Output (MVC 6)

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have an Interface to API definitions (Contracts)

```
public interface IGuidelineApi : IBaseApi
{
    ApiResult Operation(int i, string s, long l);
}
```

and Server Side API implementation prototype is like that:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class GuidelineController : IGuidelineApi
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ApiResult Operation([FromQuery]int i, [FromQuery]string s, [FromQuery]long l)
    {
        // ApiResult inherits ActionResult
        return new ApiResult(new { intVal = i, strVal = s, longVal = l });
    }
}
```

To execute any API method from any client ( MVC client app or mobile ) that using DispatchProxy can Invoke them via (API Interface) Dependency Injection

```
private readonly IGuidelineApi _guidelineApi;
public AccountController(IGuidelineApi guidelineApi)
{
    _guidelineApi = guidelineApi;

     // DispatchProxy magic here!
    _guidelineApi.Operation(1, "hello", 617);
}
```

So question is that, can I transfer the API Response to the MVC Client output (IActionResult) as directly without serialization. 
Trying just replace - override the actual response (StreamContent of Client)

Comment: I don’t really understand what you are asking; but why are you making your API return some `ApiResult` type? You can just return actual (JSON-)serializable objects, making your API simpler and more compatible without the MVC boilerplate.

Comment: Hi, need a result wrapper to provide common type to end client (Web client or mobile app) as type safety (I have interfaces - API contracts)

Comment: But `ApiResult` does not need to inherit from `ActionResult`.

Answer (score 0):

This work if you know result type:

API Call Result execute demonstration:

```
// Direct stream transport
if (response.Content is StreamContent)
{
    actionContext.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    actionContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Metadata : Type.Sample.DataSourceResult");
    await ((StreamContent)response.Content).CopyToAsync(actionContext.HttpContext.Response.Body)

    // Global Action Filter must know actual result
    return null
}
```

MVC Registered Global Action Filter:

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
{
    // Header check with extension method for type info
    if (context.HttpContext.Response.IsDataSourceResult())
    {
        // prevent end of null or empty string character!
        context.Result = new NoContentResult(); 
    }
}
```